# Ibis pandas dataframe connection

Tags: pandas, dataframe, ibis

How can we work with ibis and pandas dataframe?

```
conn = ibis.pandas.connect({'data': dataframe}) 
projection = conn.table('data')
```

It is throwing error :

```
module 'ibis' has no attribute 'pandas'
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ibis` is a connectivity tool from you python to remote Databases.

the result would be stored in pandas

so you need to use like below

```
conn = ibis.sqlite.connect('data': 'data.db')
data = conn.table('table')
```

To know more about ibis please refer this link:
https://ibis-project.org/docs/tutorial/01-Introduction-to-Ibis.html#Getting-started

Sample
[image]

Comment: I am getting the following errror.module 'ibis' has no attribute 'sqlite'

Comment: added my jupyter notebook with ibis usage

Comment: Thanks my version was 1.6.0 .Now i am working with 1.3.0 and i am able to connect to sqlite.Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear.. plz do accept this as answer and upvote if its helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have missing dependencies, maybe pandas itself. Try `import pandas` to see.

Ibis is able to connect to multiple backends. And for now, the way to specify which engine to use is by `con = ibis.<engine>.connect(...)`. So, in your case, you're correctly defining that you want to connect using the pandas engine. The problem is that Ibis supports like 15 backends, and we don't require the dependencies of all them. So, when you do `import ibis`, we try to load all backends as `ibis.sqlite`, `ibis.pandas`, `ibis.postgres`... And if dependencies are missing, we just silently stop loading the backend.

This is not great, since the error that you're getting is not very helpful, as you already discovered. In the future we're planning to change the syntax to `ibis.connect('sqlite://my_database.db')`. Once we do that, we will be able to raise an exception with the missing dependencies, if something is not right (instead of the useless `AttributeError`).

We should release Ibis 2.0 in few weeks. In the meantime, running `import ibis.backends.pandas` or `import ibis.pandas` (depending on the version you're using) should give you a more descriptive error of what's the problem.